# Opinions on improving efficiency of Excel task

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, processing-efficiency, vba

I have relatively small data set (circa 5mb) which I need to download (paid subscription) and sort on a monthly basis. I am hoping that someone can indicate a more efficient way to tackle this task.

The data is a record of planning applications within the last 30 days and whist the data is very informative, it is not organised very well - i.e. they do not provide the use type (e.g. residential, commercial, industrial etc.) nor do they provide the number of units. But they do provide a title for the application as well as a description.

An example title as follows:

> STACKVILLE - 1680 APARTMENTS/RESTAURANT/RETAIL UNITS

An example description as follows:

> Independent living scheme for older persons comprising 1100 one and 580 two bedroom apartments with support facilities  a restaurant and bar  retail units  a  cafe  20 reablement suites  parking  access  landscaping and demolition works. 1 568 sq.m

At present, I am using Excel which is somewhat time consuming. I have an ever-growing list of circa 100 use classes, as I need to determine the exact usage, which I search the title and description for. If both the title and description return the same value then I am reasonably certain that is the use classification, if it is not found it is unlikely to be of interest - although I am not 100% certain my method catches everything that I am asking it to. If they return different values then I have to do a bit of manual sift. The formula I am using as follows:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Use_Classifications!$A$1:$A$100,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Use_Classifications!$A$1:$A$100,D2)),,),0)),"Not found")
```

After I have determined them I then need to determine the number of units and put this figure into a column to the right of the data for analysis.

Can anyone recommend a more efficient way to do this? I'm currently learning Python if that helps. Would also be willing to learn almost anything to speed this up as it's very time consuming.

Comment: What does your formula do, what kind of information does it return? In the example you provide, the title and description look very dissimilar, so does that mean you would not classify it and therefore it is not of interest?

Comment: Python + pandas? (http://pandas.pydata.org/ ). Excel spreadsheet formulas are inflexible and a pain to write and VBA is a clunky language which isn't nearly as good as Python for easily extracting data from strings. Pandas gives you dataframes -- which can be thought of as virtual spreadsheets.

Comment: Thanks @JohnColeman - I thought Pandas might be able to help, only been learning Python a few months now so still trying to wrap my head around Pandas!

Comment: Thanks @halfer - the formula returns the first use classification which is found within the text. So in the above example it would return "Apartments" as my use classification list is sorted alphabetically. They do look very dissimilar which is causing the most headache, e.g. the above example returns "Apartment" which is not 100% accurate so I'm finding myself having to double check them all. I'm looking for a way to improve the accuracy and therefore reducing the time I have to spend physically checking it. Sorry if that's a little confusing, does that make sense?

Comment: I can't help on this, but are you able to merge your clarifications into the question? Just giving some feedback on understandability.